# Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (Firebase and Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, google-play-services

I know this question has been asked several times, but I can't seem to find to a work around it. I've updated all the implementations to the latest version but I still get the error below.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.3.

I'm building an app that uses firebase and maps. The project builds okay at first (without connecting to firebase) but when I do connect and add the google-services plugin, I get the error above

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is my build.gradle (Module: app) file**

```
....
dependencies 
{
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //  Android Support
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    //  Android TestImplementation
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //  Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

    //  Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'

    //  Google Sign In SDK
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can someone kindly explain to me where I'm going wrong

Comment: Please add also the content of the other `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Hey there, I was able to fix my problem by updating the google-services class to version 4.1.0 in the `build.gradle` (Project)